# How to use QPainter in a QWidget in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qpainter

My code below currently opens a 500x500 QMainWindow that is blank.

I am simply trying to draw a circle in the QWidget using QPainter.

Here is my code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, Qt
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(500, 500)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 500, 22))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

class MyMainScreen(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()  # This is from a python export from QtDesigner
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.paintCircle()


    def paintCircle(self):
        self.painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        self.painter.begin(self)
        self.painter.setPen(Qt.QPen(Qt.QColor.black))
        # painter.end()
        self.painter.drawArc(QtCore.QRectF(250, 250, 10, 10), 0, 5760)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainscreen = MyMainScreen()
    mainscreen.show()
    app.exec_()
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must override the `paintEvent` function, in your case:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, Qt
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(500, 500)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 500, 22))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


class MyMainScreen(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()  # This is from a python export from QtDesigner
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red))
        painter.drawArc(QtCore.QRectF(250, 250, 10, 10), 0, 5760)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainscreen = MyMainScreen()
    mainscreen.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: How can I get it to trigger on a double click?

Comment: In the box, basically I thought I could just say if event == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick, then drawArc but the event is ALWAYS QPaintEvent.paint every time apparently

Comment: I'm already using an eventFilter which needs mouseDoubleClickEvent

Comment: Can you get the drawArc to work on a matplotlib FigureCanvasQtAgg?

The circle shows up when the canvas doesn't exist but when I add the following three lines to the init, it doesn't show up anymore:

Comment: self.ui.centralwidget.fig = Figure((5,5), dpi=100)
##########
        
        self.ui.centralwidget.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.ui.centralwidget.fig)
        
########
        self.ui.centralwidget.canvas.setParent(self.ui.centralwidget)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use name

```
def paintEvent(self, event):
```

instead of `def paintCircle(self):` to run it automatically when it is needed.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, Qt
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(500, 500)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 500, 22))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

class MyMainScreen(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()  # This is from a python export from QtDesigner
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.ui.centralwidget.painter = QtGui.QPainter()
        self.ui.centralwidget.painter.begin(self)
        self.ui.centralwidget.painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red))
        self.ui.centralwidget.painter.drawArc(QtCore.QRectF(250, 250, 10, 10), 0, 5760)
        self.ui.centralwidget.painter.end()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainscreen = MyMainScreen()
    mainscreen.show()
    app.exec_()
```

---

Examples [draw on canvas](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pyqt/draw-on-canvas)

Comment: There's no need to keep a reference to the `QPainter` like that: just use a local variable.

Comment: @ekhumoro I used OP code and made minimal modifications.